# Audio recorder is not working on samsung s3 sprint phones

Tags: android, audio, galaxy, recorder

I have an audio recorder class to capture raw audio frames.It works on all other phone except samsung s3 sprit versions.(It works on other samsung s3 phones).I have figured out a work around for this .Problem seems wierd , so this solution may help some one to save their time.

on My audio recorder code is

```
// record init
 audioRecorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(updateListener);
 audioRecorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(framePeriod);
 if(audioRecorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED ){
    //Buffer for audio record
     buffer = new byte[framePeriod*bSamples/8*nChannels];   
    audioRecorder.startRecording();
    audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)
  }
```

and in my RecordPositionUpdate listner

```
  public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder)
  {         
   int data_Len = audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); // Fill buffer
   Log.d(TAG,"Recieved audio buffer of length "+data_Len);      
  }
```

In case of samsung s3 sprint , I can see the first read itself giving " ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION" .So the following change helped in solving the issue

```
// record init
audioRecorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(updateListener);
audioRecorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(framePeriod);
if(audioRecorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED ){
  //Buffer for audio record
    buffer = new byte[framePeriod*bSamples/8*nChannels];    
    audioRecorder.startRecording();

  //Fix for recording issue with Samsung s3 Sprint phones.Doing a delayed first read
  private final int audioRecorderSettleTime = 1500; 

  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {                    
   @Override
    public void run() {
    int bytesReceived = audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    Log.d(TAG,"Delayed first read: bytes recieved "+ bytesReceived);
    }
}, audioRecorderSettleTime);
```

}

It works fine and fix my problem .It seems like these phones have HW level issue which delays the audio recorder buffer initializations.So the first read should start after the delay time.
 IS there any way around or fix to solve the issue?

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works. One simply does not post an answer within the question block.  Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable.  You should change the above to simply phrase the question/problem.  Then give the answer below.

Comment: Not sure if this is the same issue that I'm having but after Jelly Bean AudioRecord doest work at all on Samsung S3 devices. Not sure what they broke in their build.